# 401 While Trying to get data from Yammer

Tags: json, yammer

I am trying to get/post data to Yammer using JS SDK provided by Yammer through rest API. To get data I'm using URL as "messages/my_feed.json" which is being converted to   "https://api.yammer.com/[network name]/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json" at run time  but returning 401.

[Reference http://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk]

Request further help to overcome 401 or suggest another endpoint to get/post data.

Thanks & Regards
Samik

Comment: Can you post an example code of how you are trying to do this?

Comment: Below is the sample code used-->
yam.platform.request({
        url: "messages/my_feed.json",    
        method: "GET",
        success: function (user) {
var htmlval="";
for (i = 0; i < user.messages.length; i++)
{
htmlval+=user.messages[i].body.plain+"</br>"
}
document.getElementById('spnRsp').innerHTML=htmlval;
          
        },
        error: function (user) {
          alert("There was an error with the request.");
        }
      });

Comment: This looks like a bug. The problem is you don't need the network name segment in api urls. Meanwhile you can work around it by using the full path (still no need for the host). "/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json"

Comment: While using (/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json), it appends web app url at run time and becomes (http://webappurl/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json) and also returns 401.